# Raspberry pi freeze when trying to install vlc

Tags: raspberry-pi, vlc, raspbian

I am trying to install vlc on my raspberry pi 3. Using sudo apt-get install vlc. The process starts, but eventually freezes. This is the only time it freezes and it does so every time I try. Cant reboot through ssh either. I use the official stontronica power supply, so doubt that is the problem.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Just tried it on a 2B ... it installed fine. Do you need to do a apt-get update and apt-get upgrade first ?